# Merging a custom field in the tracking alias

Tags: marketing-cloud, content-builder

Is it possible to merge fields in the tracking alias using the content editor?
I've tried:

```
%%grade%%_%%mem_ren_country_UAMSR%%_text_1
```

however that is not working. We pull tracking alias through to our GA UTM parameters.

Comment: what is the output you are currently getting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A setting needed to be turned on by Marketing Cloud support - Smart URL, once that happens you can use either standard personalisation - %%grade%% for example, or the ampscript above in the tracking alias field.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to use the [AMPscript function](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/Concat.htm) `CONCAT` to concatenate the fields in a variable and then use that in your output.

```
%%[
var @tracking, @grade, @mem_ren_country_UAMSR
set @grade = [grade]
set @mem_ren_country_UAMSR = [mem_ren_country_UAMSR]
set @tracking = CONCAT(@grade, "_", @mem_ren_country_UAMSR, "_text_1")
]%%
```

Comment: I've put the above code into the content block that contains the link, then in the tracking alias I have

<a alias="%%=v(@grade)=%%_%%=v(@mem_ren_country_UAMSR)=%%_text_1">

but I'm getting this error:
There is an error in your email.  Error 1: Script SET Statement Invalid<br>An error occurred when attempting to resolve a script expression. See inner exception for detail. 
 The function call does not end with the required close parenthesis [)]

Comment: So I've found the missing parathesis, I just need a bit more of a steer of what to put in my tracking alias. I think it should be something like this - alias="%%=v(@tracking)=%%"

Comment: You can manually add the tracking to each link or use Wen Analytics Connector to have it automatically added.

Comment: Thanks Jackson, so we pull tracking alias through to the Web Analytics Connector, I'd like this particular campaign to pull through grade and country dynamically. At the moment the code above doesn't error, but when I put this into the tracking alias - alias="%%=v(@tracking)=%%" - the output in the link is %%%3dv(%40tracking)%3d%%

Comment: Are you putting it in the HTML and not the WYSIWYG editor?

Comment: It's going into the HTML